# Multiple navigation screens from single screen in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I am developing a react Native application which have a Launch screen. launch screen is having three button which redirects to their respective stackNavigators. How should I be redirecting them to their specific screens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [switchNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/switch-navigator.html#docsNav), there is a quick example:

```
const RootNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    Auth: AuthStack,
    App: AppStack
  }
);
```

Where `AuthStack` and `AppStack` are `stack navigators`, then just call `this.props.navigation.navigate("Auth")` to navigate to the desired `stack`

Comment: Is there a way to come back to the Home screen from the Stack screens ?

Comment: Yes, switchNavigator has backBehavior prop which you can use in order to go back.